# How to Exit Program if Impossible

Tags: python, python-3.x

This isn't the full code, but here are some snippets:

```
board = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]

def solve(bo):
    
    find = find_empty(bo)
    if not find:
        return True
    else:
        row, col = find
        
    for i  in range(1,10):
        if valid(bo, i, (row, col)):
            bo[row][col] = i
            
            if solve(bo):
                return True
                
            bo[row][col] = 0
            
    return False
```

```
print_board(board)
print("")
print("Let's solve it!")
print("")
solve(board)
print("Your solved board is")
print("")
print_board(board)
```

This is a sodoku solver. How do I make it so if the board is impossible, (The solve function doesn't work) the program says "This board is impossible" then ends the program? Also, the print_board and find_empty function is in another section that I didn't show, don't worry.

Comment: `solve` seems to return `False` if solving fails, so surely just something like `if not solve(board): sys.exit()`? Probably printing a message before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

To close the program, just add the `exit()` function on the line you want the program to be exited.

You can find more info about this function here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/